# AngularJS: bootstrap-select is not shown properly when ng-options attribute is used with ng-repeat

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am using bootstrap-select (https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) to show select elements. For some reasons when I use it with ng-options and ng-repeat, it is not shown properly.

Here is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="category in categories">
        <select class="select" ng-model="status" ng-options="obj.Id as obj.Name for obj in statuses"></select>
     </li>
</ul>
```

This is what I have
[image]

Please note that <div/> is not added just below the select control.

Did someone try to solve the issue? Can I re-initialize my select elements somehow? Please advise. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
Here is how the same select looks when it is placed outside of ng-repeat.:

[image]

You can see that the select element is actually not visible (yellow box), instead <div/> is rendered just below the select element and this is exactly what a user see on the page. This is what I meant when mentioned <div /> in my initial question.

Comment: what is `<div />` who is creating it

Comment: How can I find out who created it? I am using bootstrap-select and initialize my select controls from javascript, like this jQuery('.select').selectpicker({size: 7});

Comment: that is the problem, when the `jQuery('.select').selectpicker({size: 7})` is executed the `select` elements are not present. The angular way to solve this is to write a directive

Answer (score 2):

This is because the event listner on click of `.dropdown-toggle` is not present. It is part of the bootstrap javascript package, so, you have to find out a workaround.

```js
angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('selectpicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'CA',
        link: function (scope, elem) {
            angular.element(elem).selectpicker();
            angular.element('button.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function () {
                console.log('clicked')
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry for late answer. i hope u found your answer :) 
i don't know if it's the perfect angular way answer but it worked for me

first i created a directive and create a listener for page finish loading

```
angular.module("selectBox", []).directive('selectBox', function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  link: function() {
   return $(window).bind("load", function() {
    //this will make all your select elements use bootstrap-select
    return $('select').selectpicker();
   });
  }
 };
});
```

and in your template just add

```
<select-box></select-box>
```

hope that would help :)